# Calculating xshift from node x-coordinate

Tags: positioning

Is there any way to `\begin{scope}[xshift=???]` where `???` is calculated from the x-coordinate of a node?

Example use case: I want the plot to be centered above each node; here I've just chosen an x-coordinate in each case but I want it to be calculated from a given node.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows,positioning,shapes,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm, auto,
       blockcolors/.style={
        % The rest
        thick,draw=black,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=black!10,
        font=\sffamily\small
    },
    block/.style={
        rectangle, minimum size=6mm, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=16mm,
        node distance=8mm,
        % The rest
        blockcolors,
        drop shadow
    },
    every label/.style={
        font=\sffamily\scriptsize
    },
    >=latex
    ]
\node (lions) [block] at (0,0) {lions};
\node (tigers) [block, right=of lions] {tigers};
\node (bears) [block, right=of tigers] {bears (oh my!)};

\draw[->] (lions) -- (tigers);
\draw[->] (tigers) -- (bears);

\foreach \xnode/\dx in {lions/0, tigers/2cm, bears/4cm} {
\begin{scope}[yshift=15mm, xshift=\dx]
    \draw[variable=\t,samples at={0,0.02,...,1}]
    plot (\t-0.5,{0.5*sin(2*3.14159*\t r)},0);
    \node (dot) [fill=black, circle, inner sep=0.25mm] at (0,0){};
    \draw[->] (dot) -- (\xnode);
\end{scope}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I figured it out, I can just use `shift=(ynode -| xnode)` where `ynode` is a node (or coordinate) with the y-axis position I want:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows,positioning,shapes,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm, auto,
       blockcolors/.style={
        % The rest
        thick,draw=black,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=black!10,
        font=\sffamily\small
    },
    block/.style={
        rectangle, minimum size=6mm, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=16mm,
        node distance=8mm,
        % The rest
        blockcolors,
        drop shadow
    },
    every label/.style={
        font=\sffamily\scriptsize
    },
    >=latex
    ]
\node (lions) [block] at (0,0) {lions};
\node (tigers) [block, right=of lions] {tigers};
\node (bears) [block, right=of tigers] {bears (oh my!)};

\draw[->] (lions) -- (tigers);
\draw[->] (tigers) -- (bears);

\node (baseline) [fill=black, circle, inner sep=0.25mm, label={baseline}] at (-2cm,2cm){};

\foreach \xnode in {lions, tigers, bears} {
\begin{scope}[shift=(baseline -| \xnode)]
    \draw[variable=\t,samples at={0,0.02,...,1}]
    plot (\t-0.5,{0.5*sin(2*3.14159*\t r)},0);
    \node (dot) [fill=black, circle, inner sep=0.25mm] at (0,0){};
    \draw[->] (dot) -- (\xnode);
\end{scope}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```